# Abelian subgroups of infinite unitary groups

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory

When doing quantum mechanics, a natural object to consider is $\mathcal{U}( \mathbb{H} )$, the set of unitary operators that act on square integrable wavefunctions from the Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$.

Suppose $\mathbb{H}$ is $L^2(S^1)$, $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, or $L^2(S^2)$. Then $\mathcal{U}(\mathbb{H})$ is an *infinite* dimensional Lie group (see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/infinite-dimensional+Lie+group and [What Lie group structure is used for infinite-dimensional Unitary Groups in Quantum Mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/473055/what-lie-group-structure-is-used-for-infinite-dimensional-unitary-groups-in-quan)).

I am interested in writing down *abelian* subgroups of $\mathcal{U}(\mathbb{H)}$ for these cases (and how to proceed for more general $L^2(\mathcal{X})$).

Comment: Hi Eric. This question would likely be more at home on the Math SE, so I’ve voted to migrate it.

Comment: Are you looking for a classification of abelian subgroups, or just coming up with some abelian subgroups? For the latter, you can consider any finite-dimensional subspace, say of dimension $n$, and then the abelian subgroups within this space are all contained in the maximal torus of SU($n$).

Comment: Every countable abelian group embeds in this unitary group. Also all locally compact ones. I am not sure what "writing down" could mean in this situation.

Comment: The bottom line is that we do not even have a classification of connected compact abelian groups and they all embed in your unitary group. So, the answer is "hopeless."